# Why are these U-shaped bodies of water frequent near Kura river?

Tags: water, rivers

I was looking at the Kura river in Google Maps satellite mode and I saw these U-shaped bodies of water:

[image: U-Shaped]

There are other U-shaped bodies of water too:

[40.615881° N, 47.205031° E](https://maps.app.goo.gl/ZNRfYApRkHVEnDpW6)

[40.101139° N, 47.963825° E](https://goo.gl/maps/T5KKuHs2uZRDB7Fj8)

And so many others.

Why are these U-shaped bodies of water frequent in the region?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They look like [oxbow lakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxbow_lake). Some meander scars (crescent-shaped, but dry) are also visible. Here is an excerpt of the "OXBOW" entry in *[Encyclopedia of Geomorphology](https://www.routledge.com/Encyclopedia-of-Geomorphology/Goudie/p/book/9780415863001)* (2013):

> An abandoned meander (see MEANDERING) loop along an alluvial river. It
> is the most common type of lake of fluvial origin. As a logical
> consequence of the lateral shifting and the general downstream
> migration of meanders, it develops from the interplay of channel
> erosion and accumulation separated in space. Oxbows are produced by
> meander cutoffs [...] The American name emphasizes the crescent shape,
> while in many other languages an oxbow is called a ‘dead arm’ (e.g. in
> French: *bras mort*). [...] Meander scars are oxbows completely filled
> up with mineral and organic matter. They remain discernible in the
> landscape for a long time. Classic examples are found along several
> major rivers of the world, including the Mississippi, the Amazon and
> the large rivers of Siberia.

Comment: Thank you. Sounds you're right. I also looked at Mississippi river and saw some of the same lakes there. But I think Kura river has more of them.

Comment: @SnackExchange meandering river have lots and lots of them the sediment around them is layer upon layer of them. Search oxbow lake and meandering river together.

Comment: In southern Texas, oxbow lakes formed from meanders of the Rio Grande are called "resacas."

Comment: @SnackExchange A lot also depends on how heavily altered a landscape is by humans. I'm not sure about the USA, but in Western Europe, all major rivers have been heavily altered by humans who wanted shorter shipping routes and use the land near the river.

Comment: In Australia, it's called a billabong, I believe from an Aboriginal word.  They're mostly stagnant except during the rainy season.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis All this time I thought a billabong was just a place for a swagman to spring into.

Comment: As long as he starts out camped beside it, waiting for his billy to boil.  (Under a coolibah tree.)

Comment: A big one near the Mississippi River in Louisiana is called False River.

Comment: Yes, oxbow lakes.  You could note that the Kura river has been artificially straightened in many locations, leaving behind more oxbow lakes than might be present naturally.